# Values are duplicated into all input field which is created using the ng-repeat and ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, ng-bind-html

I am using the `ng-repeat` to create the input fields dynamically, everything seems to be working fine and the input fields are created but due to some reason when I enter some value into that created input field then due to two-way data binding the value is entered simultaneously in all the text fields that were created.

As per my knowledge, I am assigning the different ng-model to each of the created fields so I am not sure why the values are being copied. When I try to print the values which are assigned to the input field just above the field then I see the id is different wanted to know why all the fields are taking the same value and also how can I prevent it.

`HTML Code`:

```
<tr>
    <td ng-repeat="extension in ExtensionList">
        <!-- Here the value displayed are different -->
        {{ formdata.extension.ExtensionVlaues }}
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="extension.ExtensionVlaues" ng-model="formdata.extension.ExtensionVlaues">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the screenshot from the front-end:
[image]

Here is the example of my `ExtensionList`: `{"Field1":"","Field2":"","Field3":1,"ExtensionVlaues":2}`

As per my knowledge, the given `ng-model` is different but still not working. Can anyone please help me with this? I tried few things like `ng-model="formdata.extension[ExtensionVlaues]"` but still no luck.

I tried to assign ng-model like this but it is not working:

1. `ng-model="formdata.extension[ExtensionVlaues]"`

Based on the below answer I tried 2 different things it but it's not working and getting the same issue. Please let me know how can I resolve this:

```
<td ng-repeat="(key, extension) in ExtensionList">
    <input type="text" ng-model="formdata.extension.key">
</td>

<td ng-repeat="(key, extension) in ExtensionList">
    <input type="text" ng-model="formdata.extension.ExtensionVlaues">
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use ExtensionList as an array.  You need to use it as an object with ng-repeat:

```
<td ng-repeat="(key, extension) in ExtensionList">
    <input type="text" ng-model="formdata[extension][key]">
</td>

<td ng-repeat="(key, extension) in ExtensionList">
    <input type="text" ng-model="formdata[extension][ExtensionVlaues]">
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this and I seeing the same issue. I have added the new code based on your comment. Can you please once look at it and help me?

Comment: Try using the bracket notation again, I edited my response above.  I am not sure what your data looks like but I would guess that `ExtensionVlause` is supposed to be `ExtensionValues`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this and its working fine now `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="extension.ExtensionVlaues" ng-model="ExtensionList.extension[key].FreeText" ng-blur="ExtensionText(ExtensionList.extension[key].FreeText, extension.ExtensionVlaues)">`

Answer (score 0):

Just incase anyone else also struck at this issue:

```
<span ng-repeat="(key, extension) in ExtensionList" class="form-inline">
    <br/>                                       
    <span>
        {{ extension.NameSpace + ":" + extension.LocalName }}
    </span>&ensp;
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="extension.ExtensionVlaues" ng-model="ExtensionList.extension[key].FreeText" ng-blur="ExtensionText(ExtensionList.extension[key].FreeText, extension.ExtensionVlaues)">
</span>
```